# After closing modal gray background remains

Tags: javascript, meteor, modal-dialog, materialize

I`m using Meteor and Materialize.
[Repo](https://github.com/CandyOgre/pizza-day).
[On hosting](https://best-pizza-day-ever.herokuapp.com/).

After closing modal, gray background not disappear! You can check it on Group page. You must create group first, then click "Add participant" and close. You`ll see it. About modals on documentation you can find at materializecss.com. Today I create "Leave/delete group" button with the same modal, and I still face with this bug. Help me please

Due to limitation, I can post just 2 links. Ask if something is not clear

Comment: Modal code [here](https://gist.github.com/CandyOgre/d7f702918460e8f9538d2f63073bd03b)

Comment: [File](https://github.com/CandyOgre/pizza-day/blob/master/imports/ui/pages/group_page/users.html) with modal html

Comment: [File](https://github.com/CandyOgre/pizza-day/blob/master/imports/ui/pages/group_page/users.js) with logics

Comment: My friend, using PHP, face with it too

Answer (score 1):

After creating that dialog window in the markup have div.lean-overlay was created. See somewhere in your code, it`s possible, you run some code 3 times. And after click "close" only 1 of 3 overlays has removed. Other two stay on the page.

Or you can hack it, just 
$('.lean-overlay').remove();
But, it`s not right way...

Comment: $('.lean-overlay').remove() is not so pretty, but works for my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to hide it when its supposed to hide.

```
$('.grayBackgroundClass').hide();
```

Also, for closing modals the code is

```
$('.modalClass').modal('hide');
```